# Получение расширения файла

Tags: android, android-intent

У меня есть метод `OnClick` в котором реализован следующий функционал:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Выберите файл для загрузки "), 1);
```

После чего открывается список файлов, после выбора переходим в метод `OnActivityResult` и там получаем `Intent` который отправили в методе `OnClick`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Как можно получить расширение файла через переменную `data` ? Мне приходит полный путь к файлу по которому я могу его достать но название не соответствует действительности. К примеру в телефоне у меня медиа файл называется `video0515.mp4` а в data мне приходит путь к файлу:

```
Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:10515 flg=0x1 }
```

и расширение никак не получается получить.

Comment: Вот как раз в URI и находится ссылка на файл content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A10734

Comment: Больше ничего толкового оттуда не вытащить, либо я плохо искал

Comment: Возвращает null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить **MIME-тип файла** из его URI нужно написать небольшой метод:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    String type = getMimeType(uri)));
}
```

Сам метод получения :

```
public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        mimeType = cr.getType(uri);
    } else {
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri
                .toString());
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                fileExtension.toLowerCase());
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```

строка `type` будет содержать MIME-тип файла.
Например, для изображения JPG получим - *image/jpg*

Две ветки в методах связаны с тем, что  URI файлов контента (как изображения, видео, аудио и тп) имеют другой формат, чем прочие файлы.

Так же можно получить и **"чистое" расширение файла** из его имени. В силу того, что в Android очень запутанная система файлов, которая делится на контент (а контент еще и по видам) и собственно файлы, да еще и зависит от API, то универсальный код получения расширения довольно громоздкий. При необходимости вы можете выбрать отдельный модуль, подходящий именно для вашей задачи (например, только файлы изображений на API 19 и выше), а не копировать весь код:

```
// метод возвращает полный реальный путь до файла, включая имя и расширение
public  String getFilePath(Uri uri) {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this, uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId( Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally { if (cursor != null)   cursor.close();
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

// метод возвращает из полного пути расширение файла
public String getFileExtension(String path) {
    int pos = path.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (pos != -1) return path.substring(pos + 1);
    else return "";
}
```

Тогда получение расширения будет происходить так:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    String type = getFileExtension(getFilePath(uri)));
}
```

где переменная `type` - расширение файла.
Например, для файла 1234.jpg она будет равна *jpg*

Для работы на API 19 и выше требуется разрешение в манифесте

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: В 1-м случае где мы получает отдельно расширение файла...я его конкатенирую с названием файла и отправляю на сервер, файл приходит битый

Comment: Я разбираю эту строку и беру расширение после "/" и подставляю в имя файла

Comment: На сервер у меня уходит имя файла "image:10734" + ".jpg" причем имя файла я получаю через  File file = new File(uri.getPath());  file.getName();

Comment: При этом файл сам называется DSC_0156.JPG а в OnActivityResult приходит далеко не это название файла

Comment: @Heaven `file = new File(uri.getPath()); file.getName();` - для файлов контента не работает, как вы сами видите.

Comment: Я просто подумал что получиться конкатенировать имя файла и расширение, вот только в процессе оказалось что проблема и с тем и с тем

Comment: @Heaven выведите, что возвращает метод `getFilePath()` и поймете, что нужно от него "отрезать". Если вам нужно работать только с файлами изображений, то этот метод можно существенно сократить (убрать все `if`, которые не относятся к Mediadocument и в нем к image), а если и API требуется только больше (или меньше) 19 , то и еще одну ветку.

Comment: Помогло, не думал что работа с файлами может создать столько проблем. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Heaven да, нелепая какая то схема, столько сложностей, согласен. Я исправил немного, забыл курсор закрыть.