# File Uri. Получить файл

Tags: java, android, файлы, uri

С помощью диалогового окна узнаю Uri файла.

```
Intent i = new Intent().setType("*/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Выбор файла"), 123);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        ....
        File f = new File(uri.toString);
        // Далее с помощью OkHttp отправляю файл...
    }
}
```

В стактрейсе пишет

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A10146
>   (No such file or directory)

Если заменить на `uri.getPath()` почти тоже самое

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:10146 (No such file or
>   directory)

При том, что файл который я открываю имеет расширение `.png` и совсем другое имя.

Comment: по расширению - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631110/177345. Там же и универсальный код для получения файла по URI (из которого потом получаем имя и из имени - расширение)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, не каждый `Uri` можно конвертировать в путь файловой системы. Конкретно ваш наверное, возможно.

Во-вторых, если есть возможность работать с потоком данных, то получить его легко:

```
InputStream fileStream = null;
try {
    fileStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);  
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Если все-таки с потоком никак, то сложнее, вот пример для файлов из галереи:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Скажите, а можно как-то узнать расширение файла?

Comment: Можно узнать `MIME`, а по нему уже подобрать расширение.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось методом `getContentResolver().getType(uri)`

Answer (score 2):

У меня такая реализация.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;

Intent i = new Intent().setType("*/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Выбор файла"), 123);


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        ....
        File f = null;

        try {
            // read this file into InputStream
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

        // Далее с помощью OkHttp отправляем файл...

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```