# Неверный путь /data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/MARS2.jpg

Tags: android

Проблема следующая: я делаю выбор файла, и делал это уже не раз, но в этом приложении, почему-то возникли трудности. Так я вызваю **filpicker**:

```
private void launchGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.dialog_photo_option_gallery)), REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
}
```

После того, как Файл выборан, результат перехватываю в **ActivityResult**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        viewModel.photoSource = ExpenseFormViewModel.PhotoSource.GALLERY;
        if(data.getData() != null){
            viewModel.imageUri = data.getData();
            updateFormPhoto();
        }else{
            //TODO: Remove
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No image selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Uri примерно вохвращется примерно такой:

*content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1877*
*content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/922*

Затем, я получаю путь по **uri**, через cursor. Достаточно распространенное решение:

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    // deal with different Uris.
    if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Вот тут-то и возникает проблема. В папках с **Picture** путь возвращается верный: */storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1503052990423.jpg*
а вот с *Recent*-папки, путь указывает на кеш:
*/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/MARS2.jpg*

Файл по такому путь нельзя открыть, и вообще ничего с ним сделать не получается. Я пробовал воспользоваться сторонник filepicker-ом, но он возвращает тоже самое. Эта проблема была протестирована на устройства android 7 и 8, и на всех возникли проблемы. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Из-за чего это возникает. Ту реализацию, которую я прсдеставил, я уже использовал ранее в других приложениях, и все работало прекрасно.

Comment: Для чего Вам нужен реальный путь к файлу? Почему бы не использовать `content://uri` и функционал провайдера?

Comment: на самом деле, мне просто нужен файл, если у вас есть какое либо готовое решение по получению File, не могли бы вы им поделиться?) Я потратил на это два дня, возможно у меня спад эффективности, либо все ссылки хранят устаревшие или не рабочие решения

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [File Uri. Получить файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658311/file-uri-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение нашлось!. Получить файл, именно файл, нужно было для отправки его request запросом на северер. Для отправки запросом в приложени предусмотрен **okhttp3**, и ввот ему-то только и нужен file. Нашли вот такую обертку на:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367888/upload-binary-file-with-okhttp-from-resources/25384793#25384793

И используем ее:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(viewModel.imageUri);
multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("extension", "jpeg")
                    .addFormDataPart("file", new Date().toString() + ".jpeg", 
                                      RequestBodyUtil.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, inputStream));
```

Всем добра, и спасибо за участие!