# Получить путь до файла из Uri

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Получить путь до файла `/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.xls`?

Не могу вытащить из: `Uri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1764`

Comment: а его и не нужно вытаскивать, используйте то что вам дала система для получения содержимого файла

Comment: @Style-7 Как, например?

Comment: Вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658326/184031

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja решение моей ситуации. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего вы пытаетесь получить этот путь в функции `onActivityResult()`. Есть например такой способ:

```
new File(uri.getPath());
```

и дальше уже можно получить путь данного файла. Но на мой взгляд это не очень хорошая практика, и лично я думаю, что лучше использовать данную функцию например для получения имени файла, или его содержимого, но никак не вытаскивания из него пути к файлу. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android) есть разные способы реализации того что вам нужно.

Comment: Это неверная практика. По ссылке, что вы приводите обьясняется, что такое работает только для схемы `file://`, в случае автора это работать не будет. И вообще в Андроид все идет к тому, что нужно абстрагироваться от файловой системы и работать преимущественно по `Uri`.

Comment: Да полностью согласен начиная с 10 версии это особенно заметно