# File в onActivityResult

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, файловая-система

Пишу приложение под андроид. Необходимо отправить фотку на сервер. Для этого из фрагмента запускаю `startActivityForResult()` При попытке по `Uri` получить файл вылетают разного рода ошибки.

```
## Код ##
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                val imageUri = data?.data ?: throw LoadImageException()
                val file = imageUri.toFile()
                vm.showToast(file.absolutePath)
                val result = Http.sendFile(vm.getUserID(), file)
                if (result == -1) throw LoadImageException()
                else vm.showToast("Успешно")
            } catch (e: LoadImageException) {
                vm.showToast("Не удалось загрузить изображение")
            } catch (e: ConnectException) {
                vm.showToast("Не удалось загрузить изображение")
            } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                vm.showToast("Не удалось загрузить изображение")
            }
        }
    }
}
private fun changeAvatarDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!).setTitle("Изменить фотографию?")
            .setPositiveButton("Да") { _, _ ->
                val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                pickIntent.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 0)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Нет") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }
            .create().show()
    }
```

После выбора фото через галерею или файловик вылетает с ошибками. Например

> Illegal argument Exception: Uri lacks file scheme.

Если вместо `imageUri.toFile()` использовать `File(imageUri.path!!)`, то вылетает

> File not found exception`

Даже не могу представить, где здесь собака зарыта

Comment: Андроид какой версии? Судя по всему связано со *scoped storage*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот это

```
val file = imageUri.toFile()
```

нельзя делать. Не каждый `Uri` является обьектом файловой системы.
Отсюда и ошибки.

Как работать с `Uri`, [смотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658311/file-uri-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/658326#658326)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, не знаю как и благодарить)

Comment: Всегда раз помочь ;)