# StartActivityForReslut возвращает uri не существующего файла

Tags: android, файлы, android-intent, uri

Я начинающий android разработчик.
Пишу небольшой fileChooser через механизм startActivityForReslut.

объект, который возвращает uri выбранного файла:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startFileChooser = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if(result==null) return;
                    if(result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        Uri uri = data.getData();

                        boolean is_ex=(new File(String.valueOf(uri))).exists();
                        if(is_ex==false)    //вот тут все время будет false при проверке существования файла с выбранным uri
                            return;
                        
                        //какие-то действия
                        //...
                    }
                }
            });
```

Функция, которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку и открывающая fileChooser:

```
private void openFileChooser(){
        Intent data= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        data.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        data.setType("*/*");
        data = Intent.createChooser(data,"Выберите файл");
        startFileChooser.launch(data);

    }
```

пример возвращаемого uri:

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AMyMusic%2F%5BDnB%5D%20-%20Muzzy%20-%20Crescendo%20(feat.%20MYLK).mp3

Вот при попытке проверить существование файла по данному uri или измерить размер файла ни чего не получается.

Два дня бьюсь на проблемой. Делал уже и через startActivityForResult -> onActivityReslut. И с Cursor игрался как вот тут [File Uri. Получить файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658311/file-uri-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb).
(курсор всегда пустой)

Вот в идеале бы получить uri вот такого формата:

> /storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/[DnB] - Muzzy - Crescendo (feat.
> MYLK).mp3

Но как это сделать совершенно не понимаю!
Очень прошу помощи! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: никаких файлов, этот uri открывайте через ContentResolver

Comment: Получить путь к файлу из `Uri` со 100% гарантией на любом аппарате невозможно, кроме того получить доступ к самому файлу тоже. Вместо этого Андроид предлагает провайдеры. С музыкой следует работать через `MediaStore`

Comment: можете подсказать, как сделать через ContentResolver? Я делал вот так:  cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);  В итоге cursor null.

Comment: InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream( uri );

Comment: так а как из этого взять нормальный uri?

Comment: Uri.parse() ....

Comment: Сорри. Не могу понять, Uri.parce() и что это даст? Плз, можете чуть подробней объяснить? я ж новичок..

Comment: Чтобы проверить существует ли файл, получайте inputstream и ловите исключение если файла нет. Размер получайте с помощью inputStream.available(). Вы не написали зачем вам это нужно и какую задачу вы решаете. Прямой путь к файлу вы получите только если сами создаете файл (и то в этом не всегда есть необходимость), со всеми остальными файлами надо обращаться через contentResolver.

Comment: задача проста: небольшой файл-менеджер, который берет uri аудио-файла и сохраняет в базу данных, чтобы затем, позднее, по этому uri запустить проигрывание аудио.