# stream = new FileInputStream(chosenUri.getPath());

Tags: android

не могу понять почему не работает FileInputStream, то есть не находит файл. через  openInputStream работает.

```
View.OnClickListener ButtonDownloadExcelOnClick=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {         
            Intent PickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            PickerIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(PickerIntent, 1);
        }
    };
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)  {
                Uri chosenUri = data.getData();
                String src = chosenUri.getPath();
                InputStream stream = null;
                try {
                   // stream = new FileInputStream(chosenUri.getPath());
                     stream  = getContentResolver().openInputStream(chosenUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Потому что это не file-uri, а content-uri - вы же запрашиваете `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

Comment: Открывайте сразу Uri не нужны никакие преобразования

Comment: Не каждый Uri есть файл. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658326/184031