# Multipart запрос (Retrofit 2.9.0) на отправку изображений с помощью activity result api не работает

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

Пытаюсь с помощью activity result api (через галерею и камеру) и retrofit составить Multipart запрос с одним партом - файлом-изображением, а другим -  именем файла формата "name.jpg". Приложение вылетает и пишет, что части с файлом не существует. Файл из телефона пытался достать через `new File(uri.getPath)`. Как сделать правильное получение пути к файлу через activity result api (в моём случае вытаскивается только uri)? + Я предполагаю, что с получением файла сразу через камеру путь достать, наверное, не получится, поэтому как тогда впринципе лучше сделать Multipart с картинкой полученной из activity result api + её именем с расширением?

retrofit service

```
public interface ClientService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("api/v1/vandalism/postImage")
    Call<Void> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart,
                         @Part MultipartBody.Part imageNamePart);
}
```

реализация activity result api

```
//latestTmpUri глобальная Uri переменная для присвоения значения из колбека

private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> selectImageFromGalleryResult =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), uri -> {
                if (uri != null) {
                    latestTmpUri = uri;
                    previewImage.setImageURI(uri);

                }
            });

    private void selectImageFromGallery() {
        selectImageFromGalleryResult.launch("image/*");
    }

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> takeImageResult =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(), isSuccess -> {
                if (isSuccess) {
                    if (latestTmpUri != null) {
                        previewImage.setImageURI(latestTmpUri);
                    }
                }
            });

    private void takeImage() {
        final Uri uri;
        try {
            uri = getTmpFileUri();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create temp file", exception);
        }
        latestTmpUri = uri;

        takeImageResult.launch(uri);
    }

    private Uri getTmpFileUri() throws IOException {

        tmpFile = File.createTempFile("tmp_image_file", ".jpg", activity.getCacheDir());
        
        tmpFile.createNewFile();
        tmpFile.deleteOnExit();

        final String authority = String.format("%s.provider", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), authority, tmpFile);

    }
```

метод отправки картинки на сервер

```
/*метод в который передаётся uri до файла в устройстве, с помощью которого 
    получаем файл в программе и его имя в устройстве
    в очередь ставится мультипарт запрос на отправку картинки и её имени
    (как метод должен работать по задумке)
     */
    public void postImage(Uri uri){

        file = new File(uri.getPath());
        
        
        RequestBody requestBodyFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);
        MultipartBody.Part multipartBodyFile = MultipartBody.Part.create(requestBodyFile);

        String imageName = file.getName();
        Log.d("name", file.getName());
        RequestBody requestBodyName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/formdata"),imageName);
        MultipartBody.Part multipartBodyName = MultipartBody.Part.create(requestBodyName);
        Call<Void> call = clientService.postImage(multipartBodyFile, multipartBodyName);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `uri.getPath()` возвращает не путь к файлу в файловой системе, а некую строку, зависящую от приложения предоставляющего выбор файла. Вы должны получить `InputStream` через `ContentResolver` и либо записать его в файл, который потом отправить; либо наследовать `RquestBody` и реализовать отправку из потока

Comment: @woesss, я не знаю как это делать) С классом ContentResolver вообще не знаком

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#open-file-stream

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658311/file-uri-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/658326#658326

Comment: @woesss, извините, я получил входной поток, как его дальше записать в файл? Разве для этого не нужен OutputStream?

Comment: Конечно нужен. Вы создаёте временный файл для записи снимка камеры - его же можете использовать и для галереи. Откройте поток `new FileOutputStream(tmpFile)` и запишите в него входной.

Comment: @woesss, я столкнулся с проблемой: какой путь мне указывать в конструкторе `new File()`? Если ставить null - вылетает NP exception для `FileOutputStream`

Comment: решил проблему с помощью `File.createTempFile()`