# Как получить абсолютный путь к файлу из Uri в андроид приложении ?

Tags: java, android, uri

Я использую

```
Intent PickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
PickerIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(PickerIntent, 1);
```

чтобы выбрать нужный мне файл (cbr, cbz, zip архивы) и в результате получаю Uri файла, после этого мне нужно вытащить из архива все файлы, но, поскольку я не нашел ни одного способа сделать этого с Uri мне нужно каким-то образом получить полный путь. Пробовал этот способ

```
public void getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, 
    null, null);
    int column_index = 
    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("gaga", "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Но он не сработал, так же пробовал filepath.getPath() - тоже не работает.
Может кто-нибудь знает проверенный и хороший способ получить путь к файлу ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631110/177345, вторая часть ответа -универсальный метод получения пути по URI

Comment: @pavlofff с этим кодом определенно что-то не так, потому что в  final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri); мы получаем полный путь к файлу, а потом эту ссылку пытаемся запихнуть в long

Comment: само имя `getDocumentId()` как бы говорит нам, что он возвращает некоторый ID, число   ... вообще этот код был оттестирован и работал на время ответа

Comment: @pavlofff в первом случае я выбрал фотографию и вернулось id, но когда я выбрал архив вернулся путь `2018-11-16 19:20:17.734 28461-28461/com.example.test.newreader E/kirin: 633`
`2018-11-16 19:20:27.265 28461-28461/com.example.test.newreader E/kirin: raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/goblin.zip`

Comment: @pavloff возникла ещё одна проблема. Некоторые Uri вызывают ошибку `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI`

Comment: Сто-процентного способа существовать не может в принципе - провайдер не обязан предоставлять такую информацию, и `Uri` может представлять вовсе не файл, а, к примеру, ресурс приложения, запись в базе, да что угодно. Я знаю только один способ гарантированно получить файл - внедрить в приложение простейший файл-браузер (реализовать самому или взять готовую библиотеку) и дать юзеру выбрать файл через него.